# Creating trigger for table in MySQL database (syntax error)

Tags: sql, mysql, database, triggers, mysql-error

I have trouble defining a trigger for a MySQL database. I want to change a textfield before inserting a new row (under a given condition). This is what I have tried:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER add_bcc
BEFORE INSERT ON MailQueue
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NEW.sHeaders LIKE "%support@mydomain.com%") THEN
    SET NEW.sHeaders = NEW.sHeaders + "BCC:internal@mydomain.com";
  END IF;
END;
```

But always I get the error "wrong syntax". I got stuck, what am I doing wrong?
I'm using **MySQL 5.0.51a-community**

BTW: Creating an empty Trigger like this works fine:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER add_bcc
BEFORE INSERT ON MailQueue
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
END;
```

But this fails, too:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER add_bcc
BEFORE INSERT ON MailQueue 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF 1=1 THEN
  END IF; 
END;
```

It's my first time to use stackoverflow.com, so I'm very excited if it is helpful to post something here :-)

Comment: What happens if you remove "SET"?  Also you should change NEW.sHeaders + "BCC:internal@mydomain.com" to CONCAT(NEW.sHeaders, "BCC:internal@mydomain.com")

Comment: I'm making this a comment not an answer because it's a guess :p

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it, but the syntax error seems to be caused by the if statement. Even the following fails:

CREATE TRIGGER add_bcc
BEFORE INSERT ON MailQueue
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF 1=1 THEN
  END IF;
END;

Sadly, MySQL does not give any good hints what the error is about...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to [change the delimiter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) - MySQL is seeing the first ";" as the end of the CREATE TRIGGER statement.

Try this:

```
/* Change the delimiter so we can use ";" within the CREATE TRIGGER */
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER add_bcc
BEFORE INSERT ON MailQueue
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NEW.sHeaders LIKE "%support@mydomain.com%") THEN
    SET NEW.sHeaders = NEW.sHeaders + "BCC:internal@mydomain.com";
  END IF;
END$$
/* This is now "END$$" not "END;" */

/* Reset the delimiter back to ";" */
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A trigger can run multiple SQL statements automatically before or after a table is changed with `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) explains a trigger in detail.

For example, you create `test` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  num int
);
```

Then, you insert the row whose `num` is `2` as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (2);
```

Next, you create `log` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE log (
  ins INT,
  upd INT,
  del INT
);
```

Then, you insert the row whose `ins`, `upd` and `del` are `0` as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO log (ins, upd, del) VALUES (0, 0, 0);
```

Now, you can create `count` trigger which adds `1` to `upd` in `log` table after a `test` table's row is updated as shown below. *You can replace `AFTER` and `UPDATE` with `BEFORE` and `INSERT` or `DELETE` respectively to run `count` trigger before a row is inserted to `test` table or a `test` table's row is deleted and in a trigger, `SELECT INTO` is allowed to use but `SELECT` without `INTO` is not allowed to use because there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474489/not-allowed-to-return-a-resultset-from-a-trigger-mysql/77561603#77561603) and basically, you need to change the default delimiter `;` to something like `$$` when creating a trigger otherwise there is error, then after creating a trigger, you need to change the delimiter `$$` back to `;` as shown below and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql/77440483#77440483) explains delimiter and you must select a database when creating a procedure otherwise there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve/77491814#77491814):

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER count
AFTER UPDATE ON test FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE log SET upd = upd + 1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, you update `num` from `2` to `4` in `test` table, then `upd` is `1` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> UPDATE test SET num = 4;
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|    4 |
+------+
...
mysql> SELECT * FROM log;       
+------+------+------+
| ins  | upd  | del  |
+------+------+------+
|    0 |    1 |    0 |
+------+------+------+
```

In addition, you can get the `num` values which are before and after update with `OLD.num` and `NEW.num` respectively. *The `num` values are stored in [the user-defined session variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) `@old_num` and `@new_num` respectively and you cannot use `OLD.num` and `NEW.num` for `INSERT` and `DELETE` respectively because there are [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681308/there-is-no-old-row-in-on-insert-trigger-error-in-mysql/77559741#77559741) and [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577565/i-have-error-1363-there-is-no-new-row-in-on-delete-trigger/77559846#77559846) respectively:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER count
AFTER UPDATE ON test FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE log SET upd = upd + 1;
SET @old_num = OLD.num, @new_num = NEW.num;
END$$        -- ↑ Here           -- ↑ Here

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, `@old_num` and `@new_num` are `2` and `4` respectively after updating `num` from `2` to `4` in `test` table as shown below:

```sql
mysql> UPDATE test SET num = 4;
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|    4 |
+------+
...
mysql> SELECT * FROM log;       
+------+------+------+
| ins  | upd  | del  |
+------+------+------+
|    0 |    1 |    0 |
+------+------+------+
...
mysql> SELECT @old_num, @new_num;
+----------+----------+
| @old_num | @new_num |
+----------+----------+
|        2 |        4 |
+----------+----------+
```

And, in this case below, you can create `count` trigger not changing the delimiter to `$$` without error:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER count
AFTER UPDATE ON test FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE log SET upd = upd + 1;
```