# MySQL Trigger to Auto-Update (or insert) Column Field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query I can run that looks like:

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) AS first_name,
   If(  length(name) - length(replace(name, ' ', ''))>1,  
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) ,NULL) 
           as middle_name,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) AS last_name
FROM people
```

While this is works great to split up the full `name` into `first_name`, `middle_name`, and `last_name` I need a way to have this done automatically; can't go in and run the query and manually update the table each time a `person` is added.

I've tried to play around with this query in the form of a trigger but keep getting errors, generally the error states `"Not allowed to return a result set from trigger"`

Any help getting this working would be great

Comment: possible duplicate of [not allowed to return a resultset from a trigger mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474489/not-allowed-to-return-a-resultset-from-a-trigger-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a BEFORE INSERT trigger, use the qualifier `NEW.` to reference values assigned to columns of the row being inserted. For example, `NEW.col` would reference the value supplied for the column `col`.

Assign a value (or expression) to `NEW.col` to replace the value supplied for column `col`, and the value assigned will be inserted instead.

A trigger to accomplish something similar to SELECT statement would look something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger 
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

   SET NEW.first_name  = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( NEW.name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1);

   SET NEW.last_name   = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( NEW.name, ' ', 3), ' ', -1);

   SET NEW.middle_name = IF(LENGTH( NEW.name) - LENGTH(REPLACE( NEW.name, ' ', ''))>1
       ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( NEW.name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1)
       ,NULL);

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

---

The error you are getting:

```
Error: 1415 SQLSTATE: 0A000 (ER_SP_NO_RETSET)
Message: Not allowed to return a result set from a %s
```

Is due to a documented restriction that applies to both `FUNCTION` and `TRIGGER`. (This restriction also applies to a `PROCEDURE` that is *called* from the context of a FUNCTION or TRIGGER.)

Comment: @jzg.dev: I didn't do any testing on that, I just copied the expressions you had in the SELECT statement, and gave an example of what a BEFORE INSERT trigger might look like. (You'll want to consider whether you need a corresponding `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, if keeping these columns "in sync" is important. In a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, the current value of the columns is available by qualifying with **`OLD.`**, for example `IF ( NEW.col <=> OLD.col )` to compare the new value with the existing value.