# Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Tags: mysql

I have problem:

I created procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `tran_sp` ()
BEGIN
  SELECT 'procedure runned!';
END
$
```

It's works !

```
mysql> CALL tran_sp()$
+-------------------+
| procedure runned! |
+-------------------+
| procedure runned! |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then i created trigger :

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger1
    ->     AFTER INSERT ON users
    ->     FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->          CALL tran_sp();
    -> END$


mysql> INSERT INTO users VALUES(166,156)$
```

**ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger
mysql>**

Help me please.

Comment: Isn't this duplicate with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12474855 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [not allowed to return a resultset from a trigger mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474489/not-allowed-to-return-a-resultset-from-a-trigger-mysql)

Comment: The duplicate is poorly phrased, so this one works better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception is I think clear enough.

You can perform additional operations inside a trigger (call a SP, perform insert / update / delete operations, ...) but all of those aren't allowed to return any result.

This means, a SP with a simple select-statement inside isn't allowed. If instead you would use this select statement within a loop for instance in order to perform updates or similar, this would be allowed, as you wouldn't return anything.

The reason is, that an insert/update/delete statement can't return anything, it can't return the result set of your stored procedure and therefor you shouldn't try to return one inside the trigger.