# How to use select query in stored procedure from trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql

**Here is my Trigger**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON SampleTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.flag =0 THEN
SET NEW.media = "../trigger/smile1.png";
ELSEIF NEW.flag = 1 THEN  
SET NEW.media = "../trigger/smile2.png";
ELSEIF NEW.flag = 2 THEN
SET NEW.media = "../trigger/smile3.png";
END IF;
CALL Media (NEW.flag);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The trigger was created successfully. And I called stored procedure from a trigger.

**procedure**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Media (a INT)
BEGIN
SELECT firstname, lastname, media FROM SampleTable WHERE flag = a;  
END $$   
DELIMITER ;
```

When I use insert query it shows the following error.

*not allowed to return a result set from a trigger*

I found select query is a reason for the error. But I don't know how to solve it.

Any Help...

Comment: may i know why you calling procedure in the trigger. because trigger does not return result

Comment: Because I want to select a row based on trigger's output.

Comment: for what purpose you selecting triggers's output.

Comment: @PRABA Same question I asked my boss. But he told to do this. Actually, He wants to run select query immediately after the trigger and also based on that trigger's output.

Comment: @Sandhiya I don no why you selecting triggers's output. but triggers does not return result. if your table having primary key id. you should try Scope_Identity(in my sql scope_identity is used as LAST_INSERT_ID()), so LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the last row output. please go through this link for further information. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/11/16/mysql-get-latest-identity-value-by-inserts/

Comment: @PRABA Thank you.

Comment: no issues.  Another way you should create another trigger but the trigger is after insert trigger. now get the last inserted row in the trigger by using old.columnnames, etc..

Comment: did you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036965/not-allowed-to-return-a-result-set-from-a-trigger ? according to it try to do something with the select statement in SP and do not return anything.