# "There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger" error in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database, triggers, mysql-error

I tried to create a trigger with `OLD.num` and `NEW.num` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON test FOR EACH ROW
SET @old_num = OLD.num, @new_num = NEW.num;
             -- ↑ Here           -- ↑ Here
```

But, I got the error below:

> ERROR 1363 (HY000): There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger

So, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The most likely explanation for getting an error

```
"There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger"
```

is that you are executing a statement that's creating an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, rather than creating an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger.

The reason that you can't reference OLD values from the row, as the row existed prior to the INSERT, is that the row did not exist prior to the INSERT.

Answer (score 25):

In an [`UPDATE TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html), you can use the `OLD` keyword to access the row data which is being replaced by the update. The `NEW` keyword allows accessing the incoming row data which will replace the old row, if successful.

An example of an `UPDATE` trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check AFTER UPDATE ON SomeTable
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       IF (OLD.LastChangedBy <> NEW.LastChangedBy) THEN
         INSERT INTO AuditSomeTable(ID, LastChangedBy) 
         VALUES (OLD.ID, OLD.LastChangedBy);
       END IF;
    END;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/122e9) here

Depending on the type of trigger created, the `OLD` and `NEW` rows may not be available to you:

*INSERT TRIGGER*

- Access to the `NEW` pseudo rows only.

*UPDATE TRIGGER*

- Access to the `NEW` and `OLD` pseudo rows

*DELETE TRIGGER*

- Access only to the `OLD` pseudo rows

i.e. there is no `OLD` row on an `INSERT` trigger, and no `NEW` row on a `DELETE` trigger.

**OP's Question**

OP hasn't provided the actual code, and the error message referred to in the comments:

> There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger

indicates that the OP had inadvertently created an `INSERT TRIGGER` and not an `UPDATE TRIGGER` as was indicated in the question. An `INSERT` trigger has no `OLD` pseudo table.

Answer (score 10):

In trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL extensions to triggers; they are not case sensitive.

In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated.

Answer (score 3):

If I get your question right..

**The answer is no! You can't have OLD.col_name in an AFTER INSERT trigger.**

For your reference in mysql ref manual it clearly dictates that :

> In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated.

[Trigger Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

here is my complete code of how trigger will work when some column value updated

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `salestatus_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `salesdata`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        IF NEW.sale_status <> OLD.sale_status THEN
            SET @changetype = 'Sale Status Updated';
        ELSE
            SET @changetype = 'Sale Edited';
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO sales_notification (sale_id, changetype, notify_to, old_value, new_value) VALUES (NEW.id, @changetype, NEW.submit_by, OLD.sale_status, NEW.sale_status);

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) says below:

> `OLD.col_name` refers to a column of an existing row before it is updated or deleted.

So, `OLD.col_name` only works for `UPDATE` or `DELETE` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON test FOR EACH ROW
   -- ↑ Here
...
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER DELETE ON test FOR EACH ROW
   -- ↑ Here
...
```