# MYSQL audit procedure and trigger

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create an audit record for table changes. For that I used this trigger

```
BEGIN
CALL proc_audit_trasabilitate(new.stare,new.serie,new.id_palet);
END
```

calling this procedure inside the trigger:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE v_username VARCHAR(50); 
SELECT @php_user_name into v_username;
INSERT INTO stari_istoric (stare,serie,id_palet,username) VALUES(p_stare,p_serie,p_id_palet,v_username);
END
```

Basically the trigger after the insert works and the username and other fields are inserted but when I use a new trigger (identical with the one for insert) after updating my table, the username is uploaded with default value, NULL.

@php_user_name is populated like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    require_once 'libraries/Audit.class.php';
    $db_ses_set = Audit::set_mysql_session_parameter('php_user_name',$_SESSION['username'],$db; }
```

with Audit.class:

```
<?php
class Audit {

public static function set_mysql_session_parameter($parameter_name,$parameter_value, $db) {
                $query = "SET @" . $parameter_name . " = '" .$parameter_value. "';";
                $result = $db->query($query);
                return $result;
           }
}

?>
```

Comment: How is the php_user_name variable populated?

Comment: Check my edit. I would also want to mention that if I use @php_user_ip the same way I use it for username, the ip is inserted in both cases (after the insert trigger and after the update trigger).

Answer (score 0):

When you use an Update trigger the :old value will be deleted and a :new value will be "inserted". I think in your case you somehow return the :old value and that's why the value is Default, NULL

1. Insert --> :new value
2. Delete --> :old value
3. Update --> :new & :old value

Comment: What is this? SQL Server? The question is tagged with MySQL. There are no inserted or deleted tables.

Comment: sorry for the last part that was SQL Server...

Have a look at the link maybe this can help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681308/get-old-value-in-mysql-trigger-after-update-statement

Comment: Your linked question discusses the issue, that there are of course no `OLD` values in an after update trigger. OP in this question here doesn't even use `OLD` values. Your very first sentence is absolute nonsense. A simple error message, that there are no `old` values would appear instead of using `new` values.