# How to get value before MYSQL update command?

Tags: mysql

I have a line:

```
Update <Table> Set <Value> = @NewValue Where RecordID = @RecordID;
```

However, now I find myself needing to update another table with the change in this value.  Obviously I could do a separate query to get the original, or I could save the original when I originally read it.  The elegant answer would be to somehow return it, though.

(RecordID is unique, this won't return multiple values.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get OLD Value in MySQL Trigger AFTER Update Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681308/get-old-value-in-mysql-trigger-after-update-statement)

Comment: @SamM That's talking about triggers which aren't going to work in my case--the second update(s) require access to three fields, one of which is found in this record, the others are defined in a config and their values are in yet another table.

Answer (score 0):

You can update both tables in one query

```
UPDATE t1
CROSS JOIN t2
SET t2.<value> = t1.<value>,
    t1.<value> = @NewValue
WHERE t1.RecordID = @RecordID1
AND t2.RecordID = @RecordID2
```

If the rows of the two tables are related, use an `INNER JOIN` instead of `CROSS JOIN`, and put the `t2` condition there.

Comment: There almost certainly are two records in t2 that need updating (and by the difference, not merely the value I'm writing) and that's simply current usage, a change to a configuration file could change the number of records affected.

Comment: You can change the `t2.RecordID = @RecordID2` to any condition you want to find the affected rows.