# Get the old data from row after update?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am just wondering if it is possible to call some method on a query before or after running update statement to get the data before updating? Of course I could just run a different select statement before running but it would be cleaner to use the same query if possible.

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO background_images VALUES (NULL,:userId, :url) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE url=:url");
        $query->bindValue(':userId', $_POST['id']);
        $query->bindValue(':url', $imageUpload->getFileName());
        $query->execute();
 
        // Somehow get the old url if the update ran?
```

Here I would like to use the old url to remove and image from a folder based on the name.

Comment: no it would not be possible, you've to pick the data first if you want to get old data using a separate `select` statement

Comment: Only way to access OLD value is using an UPDATE TRIGGER. Answer is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681308/get-old-value-in-mysql-trigger-after-update-statement

Comment: that is in `mysql` itself, in `php` you would not get that too. In `AFTER/BEFORE UPDATE trigger` you have access to old data but that is only in database itself.